# react build files run inside the xampp manifest missed

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run react build files inside the XAMPP sever. currently page is loading. but there are issues in the console. some images also not loading correctly. this is my package.json homepage settings

```
    {
  "homepage": "./",
  "name": "irf-pro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
```

this is the issues in the console.

[image]

error is mainfest.json not found and image not found.

this is my folder structure in the react build

[image]

how i fixed this issue. thank you!

Comment: The 404 errors are because of not finding a specific file. Not sure why `manifest` file is not found. regardless, the yellow text is, as it says, a warning for using something that is depricated. Sadly from the warning itself I cant pint point why. maybe some hardcore react dev could, but im not him. Posting more of the code, that causes this warning to pop up, would be helpfull. Including the code of the manifest import. Maybe then I could figure something out. If you do update it, plz @me so i get notified and check it out to help you out.